# How do I fix this 404 error on a Wordpress site page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to resolve an issue with a client's Wordpress site where when viewing one of their pages, it goes to a 404 error page. The URL in question is https://wpdev.jove.com/editorial-board-new

I've tried the solutions below:

1. Changing the permalinks to Plain
2. Inspecting the .htacess
3. Creating a new page (with no content). The 404 error still appears when viewing the new blank page.

This is what part of the .htacess looks like right now. I believe this is the part that is creating the 404 error:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z\d-]+\.)?jove\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/((methods-collections)/(industry- 
overview|test|industry-license-content|industry-create- 
content|corporate-overview|corporate-licensing|corporate- 
info|corporate-info-science-education|about|publish-in-a- 
collection|be-a-guest-editor|editorial-manager-guide-for-guest- 
editors|case-studies)|film-your-research(-2017)?|wp- 
login\.php|recommend$|recommend-jove-to-your-librarian|trial/? 
$|about|corporate|industry(?!/search)|home|in-the-laboratory|in-the- 
classroom(-2)?|blog|librarians|publish|research-partnerships|wp- 
content|wp-includes|feed|comments/feed|policies$|wp-admin|wp-json)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(new.)?jove.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L]
```

How can I fix this 404 error on [this page](https://wpdev.jove.com/editorial-board-new) on the site?

Comment: This .htaccess file expects you to have WordPress installed in a subfolder called `wp`. Do you? What does the .htaccess file inside of the `wp` folder look like.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(new.)?jove.com$` to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(new.|wpdev.)?jove.com$`

---

Below is a description of how your .htaccess file works

The first line validates the domain only has valid characters in it. I don't really know why they think this is necessary, but ok.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z\d-]+\.)?jove\.com$
```

The next link checks if we are not already in the `/wp/` folder. If we are, then we don't need to do anything more in this .htaccess file because the one at `/wp/.htaccess` will run when this one is done.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
```

The next 2 lines would check if there is not a file or directory that already exists. So in your case we would be checking that `editorial-board-new` does not already exist. If it does, we would just load that file instead of loading WordPress.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

And then we have this super long regex that will send the request to the `/wp/` subfolder if any of these matches. You can examine the regex with a site like regexr.com to get more info on what each part of the regex does.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/((methods-collections)/(industry- 
overview|test|industry-license-content|industry-create- 
content|corporate-overview|corporate-licensing|corporate- 
info|corporate-info-science-education|about|publish-in-a- 
collection|be-a-guest-editor|editorial-manager-guide-for-guest- 
editors|case-studies)|film-your-research(-2017)?|wp- 
login\.php|recommend$|recommend-jove-to-your-librarian|trial/? 
$|about|corporate|industry(?!/search)|home|in-the-laboratory|in-the- 
classroom(-2)?|blog|librarians|publish|research-partnerships|wp- 
content|wp-includes|feed|comments/feed|policies$|wp-admin|wp-json)
```

And now if all of the above rewrite conditions where true, we redirect to the same file, but inside of the `/wp/` folder.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
```

Otherwise if the url being requested uses the domain `jove.com` or `new.jove.com`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(new.)?jove.com$
```

Then we redirect to `/wp/index.php` (which loads WordPress)

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L]
```

Comment: If it helps this 404 error page happens even when I create a brand new page with no content and go to view the URL.